# Error: Can't find column `RH_train` in `.data`

Tags: r, r-caret

i'm trying to train a model with the caret Package (Random Forest), after running the "train" code, i get: Error: Can't find column `RH_train` in `.data`. Then, i tried converting the dependent variable (Rendimiento) to a factor but i get: Error: At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name; This will cause errors when class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to  X0, X0.5, X0.6, X0.65, X0.7, X0.75, X0.79, X0.8, X0.81, X0.82, X0.83, X0.85, X0.86, X0.87, X0.88, X0.9, X1 . Please use factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names  (see ?make.names for help).

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(RWekajars)
library(randomForest)
library(party)
library(caret)
library(e1071)
library(dplyr)


####Cargar base de datos####
setwd("C:/Users/Frankenstein/Downloads")
RH <- read_excel("RH.xlsx")
RH$`Año Ingreso`=NULL
RH$`Mes ingreso`=NULL
RH$`Status empleado para Gestión t`=NULL
RH$`Horario trabajo`=NULL
RH$Nacional=NULL
RH$Jefe=NULL
RH$`N Personal`=NULL

colnames(RH)
names(RH)[names(RH) == "Grado de distancia"] <- "Distancia"
names(RH)[names(RH) == "Clave para el estado civil"] <- "EstadoCivil"
names(RH)[names(RH) == "Clave de sexo"] <- "Sexo"




####Analizar la estructura del los datos#
str(RH)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   325 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Rendimiento: num  0.6 0.8 0.85 0.86 0.85 0.8 1 0.86 1 0.9 ...
 $ Edad       : num  36 37 21 26 25 28 32 32 29 36 ...
 $ Posición   : chr  "ANA" "ANA" "AUX" "AUX" ...
 $ Sexo       : num  1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Distancia  : num  5 3 1 1 3 2 2 4 5 4 ...
 $ Estrato    : num  2 5 3 3 3 3 5 2 5 6 ...
 $ EstadoCivil: num  1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 ...
 $ Hijos      : num  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ Formación  : chr  "PREGRADO" "PREGRADO" "PREGRADO" "PREGRADO" ...
 $ Educación  : num  3 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 ...

hist(RH$Rendimiento)
summary(RH)

####Dividir datos en entrenamiento y testeo####
glimpse(RH_train)
glimpse(RH_test)
RH_train <- RH[1:243, ]
RH_test <- RH[244:325, ]

# Define the control
trControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                          number = 10,
                          search = "grid",
                          classProb=TRUE)

set.seed(1234)

RH_train$Rendimiento=factor(RH_train$Rendimiento)
RendimientoFactor=factor(RH_train$Rendimiento)

# Run the model
rf_default <- train(RH_train$Rendimiento ~ RH_train$Edad + RH_train$Sexo + RH_train$Distancia + RH_train$Estrato + RH_train$EstadoCivil + RH_train$Hijos + RH_train$Educación, 
                    data=RH_train, 
                    method = "rf",
                    metric = "Accuracy",
                    trControl = trControl)
```

Comment: when using the formula interface do not use RH_train$Rendimiento, etc, but just use Rendimiento, etc in the formula.

Comment: you almost certainly do not want to model `Rendimiento` as a classification so I strongly discourage converting to factor prior to training.